How can I utilise vim's "built in" autocomplete along with LSP autocompletion?
I have N²eovim set up with the fairly ubiquitous combination of Lazy/treesitter/nvim-cmp/Mason/phpactor etc.
It works.  When I type a variable/function/class name or whatever, I get the autocompletion that I desire.
But occasionally, I'm typing something that the LSP doesn't know/care about, but I do and I'd prefer not to type it out by hand.  For instance maybe I'm typing a DB column name from a query that's on this page into a comment to explain something.
If I was running barebones vim/nvim, I'd be able to hit <c-p> to bring up the autocompletion list of any tokens on the page that match. It seems in this more advanced nvim "IDE" setup, that functionality is overwritten.  Is it possible to add it back in somehow?

Using cmp-buffer
If you are using nvim-cmp you can install a number of 'child' plugin to add completion functionalities:

cmp-nvim-lsp to have LSP completion
cmp-buffer to have 'builtin' completion (i.e. searching words in loaded buffers)
cmp-path to have path completion from the filesystem

In your case I suppose you need to add: cmp-buffer

Use coc.nvim
If you are using coc.nvim that supports both Vim and Neovim you'll have that functionality.
coc.nvim suffixes the possible completion using the completion source:

A for buffer list
LS for language server
...



@Codemonkey, I have found a solution using nvim-cmp I have adapted the answer accordingly.
